# Медленно работает ноутбук при поиске данных

Tags: python, csv, amd, radeon

В общем есть файл csv там 2 394 105 рядов. Это же нормально что при поиске 5 наибольших значений ( использовал pandas, merge sort, разбивания файла на части, а также разные решения на stackoverfow ) ноутбук перестает адекватно работать в лучшем случае или же просто перестает отвечать.
Или это я его угробил, так как замерял скрипт выпоняется за ~0.5 секунд

```
Processor: AMD A6-6310 APU with AMD Radeon R4 Graphics
Memory (Gb): 3.3
Video: [AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics]
Частота процессора : 1.8
Ядер : 4
```

Comment: Какой объем CSV файла? Вы можете показать 2-3 первых строки файла, чтобы было понятно какие типы данных Pandas будет использовать? RAM `3.3GiB` - это очень мало по нынешним временам....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю использовать следующий подход - читаем CSV файл порциями (скажем по 50.000 строк), в каждой порции находим 5 наибольших значений и собираем эти пятерки строк для всех порций. Получится ~240 строк - в конце выбираем 5 наибольших значений из этих 240 строк.

Код:

```
import pandas as pd

reader = pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=50000)
df = pd.concat([x.nlargest(5, ['column_name']) for x in reader], ignore_index=True) \
       .nlargest(5, ['column_name'])
```

Рабочий пример:

создаем CSV размерности: 2.000.000 x 4:

```
In [9]: N = 2*10**6

In [10]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10**6, size=(N, 4)), columns=list('abcd'))

In [11]: df
Out[11]:
              a       b       c       d
0        544911  248558  682940  566091
1        626200  861702  634977  775530
2         73333  787911  683934  671436
3        757572  873402  132411  793515
4        525953  352089  137649   57312
5        614804  135635  962440  201649
6        963113  727240  547785  445423
7         33479  152420   33551  157264
8        204983  158132  991536  640985
9         46894  777635  484413  704125
...         ...     ...     ...     ...
1999990  431655  121256   68473  791527
1999991  914792  451371  350977  706166
1999992  914021  939089  292477  254195
1999993  729520  932903  765863  377807
1999994  373197  620125  428411  744849
1999995  113547  636763  336648  548497
1999996  474638  363756  913728  660371
1999997  884484  543845    2134  369019
1999998  775173  368943  633521   63109
1999999  179729  252319  695091  793691

[2000000 rows x 4 columns]

In [12]: df.shape
Out[12]: (2000000, 4)

In [13]: df.to_csv(r'C:\tmp\a.csv', index=False)
```

Чиатаем порциями и находим 5 строк с наибольшими значениями в столбце `a`:

```
In [16]: df = pd.concat([x.nlargest(5, ['a']) for x in reader], ignore_index=True) \
    ...:        .nlargest(5, ['a'])

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
          a       b       c       d
65   999999  508545  190478   31434
155  999999  332700  595657  190298
45   999998  751454  407814  980328
85   999998  692764   71985  773586
190  999998   79212  549233  374016
```